# Measure very small current with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, current-measurement, current-transformer

I have to make a circuit/device in which i have to measure very small current in a wire carrying ac current.

In a given scenario, there will be a live wire carrying as low as 0.2A and as high as 100A. To measure this safely, I'll always be using a CT of 100/5 specs. The problem:

When the load current is too small, like 0.2A, the current induced in CT will be 0.05 times that. That will  too small to measure using an arduino. I know the basic concept that we use a burden resistor to translate the current into a voltage drop and then measure that using the adc. But the voltage is turning out to be too less probably. **What is the right value for a burden resistor? How to measure this current properly?**

**Note: I need help with measuring only the small current in the CT part. And by small I mean 10mA to 100mA**

Comment: Three orders of magnitude range means you must come up with a way to cover that range. If you keep it linear, which is all that a resistor will do, then you need to accept three orders of linear range. If you take the logarithm, then a short linear stretch may suffice well. But you will need to make it up in software handling. You could also use range switching, like some voltmeters do, but you may loose samples while that takes place. What do you want the Arduino to see for 0.2A? What also, for 100A? (Come up with a `V=f(A)` formula that you like and tell us what it is.)

Comment: For example, you might want `V=1.3+0.75*ln(A)`. That would give almost 100 mV at 0.2 A and about 4.75 V at 100 A. But there isn't a `properly` here. That's your call.

Comment: @periblepsis i understand what you are saying about switching ranges, but that is okay, i'll deal with that later. My main obstruction is measuring the small magnitude of ac current, 10mA -500mA.

Comment: There are commercial. current clamp meters, but you will need two different models, a low current model with 200 mA or 1 A range and a high current model with a range of 100 or 200 A.

Comment: @Uwe I want to do it using an arduino!

Comment: You need to specify your resolution and does this apply across the current range from 10ma  (which you changed from 200ma) to 100A.

Comment: But with an Arduino you would need two different sensors too. If you use only one sensor with a 100 A range you will get low precision and resolution for a 200 mA.

Comment: @Uwe Correct, help me with the small current bit, i'll get to the rest later.

Comment: Assuming a two-range approach, how fast do you need to be able to transition between the two ranges?

Comment: You need to consider the burden resistor value carefully. The burden resistor converts the current flowing through the CT into a voltage that can be measured by the Arduino's analog-to-digital converter (ADC).

Comment: "very small" and "0.2A" seem a bit contradictory...

Answer (score 3):

You can build something simple that will accomodate for both low and high currents. As you said, using just a resistor will be a problem because it is linear, and if you want to have high accurracy at low currents, you will exceed your range at high currents.

The trick is to have something that isn't linear. A kind of "logarithmic resistor" would be nice. That is actually what a diode is, but it lacks accuracy, is highly temperature-dependent, etc... But if you make a clever combination of resistors and diode, you can find a compromise.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnp3y8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This will result in an I/V response with two linear sections: one with a steep slope for low currents, to get enough accuracy, and another with a flatter slope to reach high current range (but less accuracy obviously). The knee happens at the value of the diode voltage drop. It also makes it easy to translate from voltage to current in software without relying on bulky math libs, and using very little MCU resources.

Here is the response of this example circuit (for 1-200mA input). You can see the slope of the first part is 50V/A (R2+R1) and on the second part it switches to 10V/A (R1).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> as low as 0.2A and as high as 100A

So a dynamic range of 500, but you need more than this if you want good precision on the low range.

**Readymade solution:** use an [energy metering chip](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/energy-metering/765). These are intended to measure power, but will also measure RMS voltage and current. They contain the required ADC and RMS calculation engine (a small DSP).

**Intermediate solution:** use a 24 bit sigma delta ADC with adequate sample rate to do RMS calculation on the arduino.

**Manual solution:** use the Arduino's ADC.

It will need an accurate voltage reference (not the power supply).

Regarding sample rate, even a 8-bit AVR will be able to do a RMS calculation at least at 20kHz so that's alright for mains frequency.

Arduinos have a wide variety of microcontrollers, and therefore many different ADCs. With a 12 bit ADC (0-4096) and full scale on 100A RMS you get about 3 bits to sample the low end of your range (0.2A) which is not really good for accuracy. If you got a 10 bit ADC then it's even worse. So you need range switching.

**100/0.001 transformer**

[image]

If you get a CT that will output a few mA full scale, you can use a transimpedance amplifier. The drawback of this is that the whole CT current goes through the opamp output, the advantage is that it's a simple circuit. Range switching is done by switching feedback resistors with IC analog switches. Diodes protect the input of the opamp, and the output is centered on VREF/2 in the middle of the ADC range.

**100/5 current transformer**

(Note: the switch should be on the other resistor, I made a mistake)

In this case full scale current will be 5A which is rather high, so you will need a low value burden resistor and adequate protection for the input. With a 0.1R burden resistor, you will get 0.5V RMS, but it will dissipate up to 2.5W, so a lower value like 10 mOhms may be preferable.

[image]

With 10 milliohms, 100A input gives 5A at the CT output, thus 50mV on the resistor, with 0.25W dissipation. 0.2A on the input gives 100µV. All values RMS.

In peak values that's 70mV peak or +/-70mV, so with a 3.3V ADC measuring from 0V to 3V3 we need a gain of 23. Let's go with 22, this will amplify +/-70mV to +/-1.54V, zero being the middle of the 3.3V reference voltage or 1.65V. So the ADC range will be well utilized.

An analog switch can be used to add ranges. Here when the switch is on, the 2.2k resistor is in series with the 100k resistor, producing a gain of 21.5. When the switch is off, gain is 1000.

Using MOSFETs to switch several values of burden resistors can be done, but care should be given to not measure burden voltage across the RdsON of the MOSFET, which would introduce a significant error. The same problem exists in the above circuits, as the switch's internal resistance adds to the feedback resistor.

[image]

In this version, the first opamp applies a gain of 22, which is suitable for the 100A range. Then the second opamp applies a gain of 45. This does not need switches: it simply relies on the micro having several ADC input pins, so it can select which opamp output to monitor. The capacitor removes opamp offset which would be a problem at high gain.

MCU input protection against overvoltage from the opamp output should be added.